# UITableViewCell - subviews re-layout after scrolling stops

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I've a custom UITableViewCell with some expanding menu inside it.
Cell with menu looks like this:

```
+--------------+
|(>)--(a)--(b) | (cell#1 - expanded)
+--------------+
+--------------+
|(<)           | (cell#2 - not expanded)
+--------------+
> = root menu button
a = expanded item 1
b = expanded item 2
```

Because cell is re-used, I need to close menu (if it's expanded), when cell is dequeued, so the new-dequeued cell will appear with menu closed.

Problem is, that menu in dequeued cell won't close until table view scrolling stops.
Is there any way to close menu right after cell is dequeued ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I had to use "current NSRunLoop mode":

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(animateItemToStartPoint:)
              withObject:dictionary
              afterDelay:animation.delayBetweenItemAnimation * x
                 inModes:@[[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] currentMode], NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use method `-(void)prepareForReuse` in your cell. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) is the description of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what is your problem without a code to analyse but you can implement this in your `cellForRow` method using a custom cell with a `isMenuOpened` property and a `closeMenu` something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    YourCustomCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[YourCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      //perform init setup here or other ops
    }
    else { 
       if(cell.isMenuOpened) {
           [cell closeMenu];
       }
       //do other setup here, set text and other stuffs
    }

   return cell
}
```

The method suggested by *xexe* is ok when you are using light properties changes such as `alpha` and properties that are not related with the content, for performance reasons.

Comment: This doesn't help.
Here is video of problem: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCR0-DfvkT4

And here is demo project:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2261256/development/menuTest.zip